# Enviando dados do Servidor para Cliente (LOCAL)

Tags: python-3.x

Estou com a necessidade de enviar dados de uma função do servidor para o cliente usando a biblioteca *socket* porém durante o envio das informações para o cliente as mesmas chegam em branco, a variável que recebe a funções imprime o conteúdo no servidor porém no cliente os dados chegam em vazios.

Código do Servidor

```
    import socket, psutil
    # Cria o socket
    socket_servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Obtem o nome da máquina
    host = socket.gethostname()
    porta = 9999
    # Associa a porta
    socket_servidor.bind((host, porta))
    # Escutando...
    socket_servidor.listen()
    print("Servidor", host, "esperando conexão na porta", porta)
    # Aceita alguma conexão
    (socket_cliente,addr) = socket_servidor.accept()
    print("Conectado a:", str(addr))


#terminou = False
while True:
    info = ("\n 1 - Uso de Processamento \n 2 - Memoria \n 3- Arquivos e Diretórios\n 4 -Processos Ativos \n 5- Redes \n Pressione $ para encerrar a conexão")
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia resposta
    # Decodifica mensagem em UTF-8:
    msg = socket_cliente.recv(1024)
    if '$' == msg.decode('utf-8'): #Termino do cliente
        info = ('Conexão encerrada')
        socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print("Fechando conexao com", str(addr), "...")
        socket_cliente.close()
        break
    if '1' == msg.decode('utf-8'):
        info1 =('Usuario solicitou Informações de uso de processamento')
        socket_cliente.send(info1.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info1)
        break
    if '2' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info2 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre Memoria')
        def mostra_uso_ram():
            mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
            print('Memoria Total',mem.total/(1024*1024*1024))
            print('Memoria Usada',mem.used/(1024*1024*1024))
        mem = mostra_uso_ram()
        socket_cliente.send(mem.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info2, mem)
        break
    if '3' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info3 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre arquivos e diretorios')
        socket_cliente.send(info3.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info3)
        break
    if '4' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info3 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre processos ativos')
        socket_cliente.send(info3.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info3)
        break
    if '5' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info3 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre Rede')
        socket_cliente.send(info3.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info3)
        break
    else:
        dif =('O usuário Digitou opções invalidas.')
        socket_cliente.send(dif.encode('utf-8')) # Envia resposta
        socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia resposta
        print('O usuário Digitou opções invalidas.')
        break
```

Código CLiente
    # Cliente
    import socket, sys

```
host = socket.gethostname()
porta = 9999

# Cria o socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
# Tenta se conectar ao servidor
    s.connect((host,porta))
except Exception as erro:
    print(str(erro))


print('Conexão efetuada com',host)
#Recebe informações disponiveis
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
while True:
    #Aguarda usuario digitar opção para monitorar
    menu = input(str('Digite a opção que deseja monitorar:'))
    s.send(menu.encode('utf-8')) #Envia opção escolhida pelo usuario
    #recebe informações
    info = s.recv(1024)
    print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso de ser a opção 2 a tua função não estava a retornar nada, deves retornar ou acontece o erro, para além de estar mal posicionada.

Também não estavas a enviar como resposta para o cliente em `bytes`:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Código com o problema corrigido:

Servidor:

```
import socket, psutil

def mostra_uso_ram():
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    text = '\nMemoria Total: {}'.format(mem.total/(1024*1024*1024))
    text += '\nMemoria Usada: {}'.format(mem.used/(1024*1024*1024))
    return text

# Cria o socket
socket_servidor = socket.socket()
socket_servidor.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
# Obtem o nome da máquina
host = socket.gethostname()
porta = 9999
# Associa a porta
socket_servidor.bind((host, porta))
# Escutando...
socket_servidor.listen()
print("Servidor", host, "esperando conexão na porta", porta)
# Aceita alguma conexão
(socket_cliente,addr) = socket_servidor.accept()
print("Conectado a:", str(addr))


#terminou = False
while True:
    info = ("\n 1 - Uso de Processamento \n 2 - Memoria \n 3- Arquivos e Diretórios\n 4 -Processos Ativos \n 5- Redes \n Pressione $ para encerrar a conexão")
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia resposta
    msg = socket_cliente.recv(1024)
    print(msg)
    if '$' == msg.decode('utf-8'): #Termino do cliente
        info = ('Conexão encerrada')
        socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print("Fechando conexao com", str(addr), "...")
        socket_cliente.close()
        break
    if '1' == msg.decode('utf-8'):
        info1 =('Usuario solicitou Informações de uso de processamento')
        socket_cliente.send(info1.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info1)
        break
    if '2' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info2 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre Memoria')
        mem = mostra_uso_ram()
        socket_cliente.send(mem.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info2, mem)
        break
    if '3' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info3 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre arquivos e diretorios')
        socket_cliente.send(info3.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info3)
        break
    if '4' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info3 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre processos ativos')
        socket_cliente.send(info3.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info3)
        break
    if '5' == msg.decode('UTF-8'):
        info3 = ('Usuario solicitou Informações sobre Rede')
        socket_cliente.send(info3.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem
        print(info3)
        break
    else:
        dif =('O usuário Digitou opções invalidas.')
        socket_cliente.send(dif.encode('utf-8')) # Envia resposta
        socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia resposta
        print('O usuário Digitou opções invalidas.')
        break
```

CLiente:

```
import socket, psutil
host = socket.gethostname()
porta = 9999

# Cria o socket
s = socket.socket()
try:
# Tenta se conectar ao servidor
    s.connect((host, porta))
except Exception as erro:
    print(str(erro))


print('Conexão efetuada com',host)
#Recebe informações disponiveis
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
while True:
    #Aguarda usuario digitar opção para monitorar
    menu = input('Digite a opção que deseja monitorar:')
    s.send(menu.encode('utf-8')) #Envia opção escolhida pelo usuario
    #recebe informações
    info = s.recv(1024)
    print(info.decode())
```

### Outra versão

Ao brincar um pouco com o teu código acho que consegui melhorar e aumentar a escalabilidade:

Servidor:

```
import socket, psutil

def mostra_uso_ram(socket_cliente):
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    info = '\nMemoria Total: {}'.format(mem.total/(1024*1024*1024))
    info += '\nMemoria Usada: {}'.format(mem.used/(1024*1024*1024))
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8'))

def uso_process(socket_cliente):
    info = '\nUsuario solicitou Informações de uso de processamento'
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8'))

def close_conn(socket_cliente):
    socket_cliente.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    socket_cliente.close()

def arqui_dirs(socket_cliente):
    info = '\nUsuario solicitou Informações sobre arquivos e diretorios'
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem

def active_procc(socket_cliente):
    info = '\nUsuario solicitou Informações sobre processos ativos'
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem

def network(socket_cliente):
    info = '\nUsuario solicitou Informações sobre Rede'
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8')) # Envia mensagem

opts = {
    '$': ('pressione $ para disconectar-se', close_conn),
    '1': ('Uso de Processamento', uso_process),
    '2': ('Memoria', mostra_uso_ram),
    '3': ('Arquivos e Diretórios', arqui_dirs),
    '4': ('Processos Ativos', active_procc),
    '5': ('Redes', network),
}

menu_text = '\n'
for opt, (opt_text, func) in sorted(opts.items()):
    menu_text += '\n{} - {}'.format(opt, opt_text)

# Cria o socket
socket_servidor = socket.socket()
socket_servidor.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
# Obtem o nome da máquina
host = socket.gethostname()
porta = 9999
# Associa a porta
socket_servidor.bind((host, porta))
# Escutando...
socket_servidor.listen()
print("Servidor", host, "esperando conexão na porta", porta)
# Aceita alguma conexão
socket_cliente, addr = socket_servidor.accept()
print("Conectado a:", str(addr))

socket_cliente.send(menu_text.encode())
while True:
    # Decodifica mensagem em UTF-8:
    try:
        msg = socket_cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    except Exception as err:
        break
    if(msg == '$'):
        close_conn(socket_cliente)
        break
    elif(msg not in opts):
        socket_cliente.send('Opção inválida'.encode())
    else:
        opts[msg][1](socket_cliente)
    socket_cliente.send(menu_text.encode())
```

Cliente:

```
import socket, psutil
host = socket.gethostname()
porta = 9999

# Cria o socket
s = socket.socket()
try:
# Tenta se conectar ao servidor
    s.connect((host, porta))
except Exception as erro:
    print(str(erro))


print('Conexão efetuada com',host)
#Recebe informações disponiveis
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
while True:
    #Aguarda usuario digitar opção para monitorar
    menu = input('Digite a opção que deseja monitorar:')
    s.send(menu.encode('utf-8')) #Envia opção escolhida pelo usuario
    #recebe informações
    info = s.recv(1024)
    print(info.decode())
```